# Python: List of URLS to text list in Python (Excel)

Tags: python, excel, url, twitter

I have a list of URLs to tweets in Excel. Is it possible to take out the text from these tweets (URLs) in Python? And later save it in the Excel sheet?

I saw someone used the code below, but this is only only for 1 URL.

```
from lxml import html

import requests

page = requests.get('https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1237448419284783105')

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "permalink-tweet-container")]//p[contains(@class, "tweet-text")]//text()')
```

The excel containts with columns: author and URL.
The excelfile ('twitter.xlsx') looks like this:

```
Author              URL
realDon..      https://twitter.com/realDon..
.                         .
.                         .
.                         .
```

I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from lxml import html
import requests

input_data = pd.read_excel('twitter.xlsx')

input_data1 = input_data[['URL']]

tweets = []
for url in input_data1.values:
x = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(x.content)
i = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "permalink-tweet container")]//p[contains(@class, "tweet-text")]//text()')
tweets.append(i)
```

Error:
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '['https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1237448419284783105']'

Comment: As a workaround, if handling Excel and using XPath turns out to be too complex for now, you could save the Excel file as a CSV file and start from there. If you do not need Excel-specific functionality, this will be much easier. You can still work with CSV files by using Excel.
Cf. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html

Comment: _Is it possible to take out the text from these tweets (URLs) in Python? And later save it in the Excel sheet?_ Most likely, yes. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - yes.

Long answer - yes, it's possible. I suggest you do some reading on the topic.

- https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/ covers how to manage and manipulate excel files. The `openpyxl` library is your friend here - [here's their documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).
- `requests` is a great library to use for getting access to websites! [Here is their documentation](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Here's a pseudo code mock up of what your program logic could look like:

```
input_data = read(excel_file)
tweets = []
for url in input_data:
    x = get(url)
    tweets.append(x)
for tweet in tweets:
    write(tweet, excel_file)
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried your approach but it did not work as I wanted. I reformulated my question from above. It would be of enormous help if you could take a new look at it.